# Future builder not building list view in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-listview

I am new to flutter and I am trying to build up a list from what I have saved in shared preferences.
I was able to build the list with the future builder by calling async function getTitles() in the future builder widget directly, but because of the rebuilding issues of the future builder, I have changed my code as below.

But now my List is not getting populated can someone guide me where I am doing wrong.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'my_shared_preferences.dart';
    import 'editable_list_tile.dart';

class ModesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ModesScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ModesScreenState createState() => _ModesScreenState();
  String title;
}

class _ModesScreenState extends State<ModesScreen> {

  late Future<dynamic> _future;

  List<ListModel> list = [];
  List<String> _modetitlelist = [];
  List<String> _modesubtitlelist = [];

  _ModesScreenState() {
    _modetitlelist.clear();
    _modesubtitlelist.clear();
    int ind = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      MySharedPreferences.instance
          .getStringValue('modelname$i')
          .then((value) => setState(() {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          _modetitlelist.add(value);
        } else {
          ind = i + 1;
          _modetitlelist.add('Mode $ind');
        }
      }));
      MySharedPreferences.instance
          .getStringValue("preset$i")
          .then((value) => setState(() {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          _modesubtitlelist.add(value);
        } else {
          _modesubtitlelist.add('0');
        }
      }));
    }
  }
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = _getTitles();
  }
  Future<dynamic> _getTitles() async {
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      list.add(ListModel(title: _modetitlelist[i], subTitle: _modesubtitlelist[i]));
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //title: Text(widget.title),
        title: const Text('Modes & Preset'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => EditableListTile(
              model: list[index],
              onChanged: (ListModel updatedModel) {
                /// Gets called when the save Icon is tapped on the List Tile.
                list[index] = updatedModel;
                MySharedPreferences.instance
                    .setStringValue("modelname$index", list[index].title);
                MySharedPreferences.instance
                    .setStringValue("preset$index", list[index].subTitle);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use streambuilder instead of future builder. future builder generates data everytime the ui changes. streambuilder changes only on posted events

Comment: Is stream builder a good idea for data from shared preferences? Any corrections you see in the above code to make it work.

Comment: a very popular model for coding in flutter is bloc (business logical component) and streambuilder.  bloc receives an event and then it outputs a state.  The state object is processed by streambuilder.  In this case the outputted state would contain a list of items which the stream builder would use to render the ui.  Let me work up an example